# Netdom Join -- What is wrong with this syntax?

Tags: active-directory

I receive `'The syntax of this command is:...Try "Netdom Help" for more information`, when I enter the following:

```
netdom join melbourne /D:contoso.internal /UD:administrator /PD:*
```

I have both machines running in oracle box. Both are W2K8R2. ADDS, DNS, and DHCP are installed. I can ping back and forth by DNS and IP. I can SMB to fileshares as well. I also tried the above command with a created domain admin account, with same result.

The error message is not helpful. Can someone tell me what I am missing, or what else I should check?

EDIT: I posted the question with improper syntax. In my testing I did precede the parameters with slashes, I did not, however, include them in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax (at least as you posted it in your question) is incorrect.

It should be:

```
netdom join melbourne /Domain:contoso.internal /UserD:contoso\administrator /PasswordD:*
```

You can run:

```
netdom help join
```

to see the full syntax and options.

Also, in your example, you specify the user as `administrator`, which will refer to the local administrator account (which of course has no permission to add computers to the domain).  You must qualify it (`contoso\administrator` or `administrator@contoso.local`).

Comment: I believe the abbreviations I used are valid syntax. [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776879%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) technet page. I also tried with the full parameter syntax, and multiple variations of entering the password and the domain\username. The `help` isn't. I am following the syntax as described in the link, AFAI can tell.

Comment: yes, you can abbreviate, but you still need the slashes "/" in front of the abbreviations.

Comment: Ah. I see. That is a typo on my part. I will edit the question. Thanks to your suggestion, though I resolved the issue. For the `/UD:` parameter I did not use the `contoso\administrator` format. I tried it with that and it went right through.

Comment: Yep...as just "administrator" will result in using the local administrator account, not the domain one.